# initiate 2d array with given ordered datasets

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I don't know how to search key words in my case in search engine.
I want to make a 2d-array and each column means (x,y,z) from given 3 arrays.

```
x = [3,6,9,12]
y = [4,8,12,16]
z = [5,10,15,20]
```

to this:

```
[3,4,5],
[6,8,10],
[9,12,15],
[12,16,20]
```

my code is like below, is any better way to write this?

```
x = [3,6,9,12]
y = [4,8,12,16]
z = [5,10,15,20]
count=0
ans = []
for ind1 in range(4):
    ans.append([x[count], y[count], z[count]])
    count +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use numpy here.

```
import numpy as np
xyz = np.zeros((4, 3))
x = [3,6,9,12]
y = [4,8,12,16]
z = [5,10,15,20]
xyz[:, 0] = np.reshape(x, -1)
xyz[:, 1] = np.reshape(y, -1)
xyz[:, 2] = np.reshape(z, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `zip`

```
[ins] In [1]: x = [3,6,9,12]
         ...: y = [4,8,12,16]
         ...: z = [5,10,15,20]

[ins] In [2]: [list(x) for x in zip(x,y,z)]
Out[2]: [[3, 4, 5], [6, 8, 10], [9, 12, 15], [12, 16, 20]]
```